# Android x86 on DELL INSPIRON 1501

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-x86, dell

I can't run android-x86 (4.4 RC2) on my notebook (dell inspiron 1501) well

the first problem is :

Graphics : Radeon Xpress 200M

my `/proc/fb` : 0 ATI Radeon 5975

I can use at most 1024x768x16 (vga = 791)
but my native resolution is 1280x800x32 and if I use this in kernel (or even 1280x800x16) it shows `A  N  D  R  O  I  D` and graphic ui doesn't show up. just a blinking underline in the middle of page. and I can write terminal commands  like `cat /proc/fb` there !

==================================

the second problem is :

I can not turn on my `Broadcom 802.11g Network Adapter` in android-x86

==================================

if there is a release of android-x86 (preferred : 4.0+, second choice 2.3+) or a way to solve it please tell me

Thanks

**EDIT :** installed 4.3 4.2 4.0 still no luck

Answer (score 3):

Your device isn't listed in the [list of supported notebooks](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjREKzGKF9TDdEd1MW9SR1pSeGdzbUk0RTZuV1Z2SVE&usp=sharing#gid=8), so it's not surprising that it doesn't work. You'll have to wait until it's supported.

Remember that the Android-x86 project is made by volunteers, so support for particular hardware depends on someone with the necessary skills having that hardware and an interest in making it work. You might be able to help speed the process along by buying a similar device for the project (that they can test on), or by helping to update documentation or such to help free their time for porting. If you want to help get your device supported faster, in the first instance you should contact [their discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-x86) and ask what you can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

wrong wrong wrong it's not about he's laptop "is not supported" kitkat have issue with Radeon graphic cards there is small solution for that you have to change destination library for source to start graphic acceleration I have Lenovo T400 with radeon it run only in debug mode 2 and most important it start only with selected DEBUG NOMODESET KITKAt start with 860  x resolution. I try to edit almost all possible graphic ( important kitkat support only 16 bit color) [image: Resolutions]

so even if you will be able start os you will not have graphic acceleration. I saw one solution  when i will test it and it will work i will drop info here , Sorry for all typo and mistakes (English is not my native language )

PS. On Samsung Laptop 3530 intel 3000 vga - installation and setup took few minutes no problems at all (Radeon usually older cards have that problem) If anyone will have 100 % tested solution please give me a shout Good Luck Everyone

Almost forgot using KITKAT 4.4.2

and this works for me 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/android-kitkat/-AupM37ELEM

Comment: OpenGL ES hardware acceleration for AMD Radeon and Intel chipsets (not include the PowerVR chips).

Comment: I'm not sure how your "have issue with Radeon graphic cards" is different from my "is not supported". What exactly are you suggesting Mr Tahernejad should do?

Comment: You mean if I install android ICS or JB it will work fine ?! no it isn't! I have the same problem with them, and for 4.3 it restarts immidiately after boot selection in any mode. even with lowest possible mode I wrote in kernel=

Comment: what the heck are you talking about this is topic about Android XDA 86 PC ( Personal Computer ) so no jailbreaks are required its Already rooted  if you need advise provide full specification on what device did you installed and how and from where

Comment: @Wurt ha ?! :| JB = JellyBean :|

Answer (score 0):

For My laptop only solution was change in bios settings becaouse i have radeon and intel vga
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-kitkat/-AupM37ELEM

Comment: nope I have just radeon! no intel VGA.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is all I can advise for this topic:

1. Find drivers for Linux for this card (test on Linux to see if it works properly)
2. Android x86 have different location of resource folder (additional drivers)
3. Find on androidx86 where exactly you have to copy driver's
4. Start new installation of Android Kitkat 4.4.2 x86 version  with drivers included in specific folder
5. - It works.
   - If not, you should be able to see on screen where it stops during first boot and after installation (drop screenshot(s) here)
6. If you don't see anything, try debug mode and then drop screenshot(s) here.